# ModuleNotFoundError when importing file from the same directory

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I would like to import python file inside the SAME directory.

Module Structure

```
example_module
   models
      connectors
         Constants.py
         example_connector_1.py
         example_connector_2.py
      example_file_1.py
      example_file_2.py
      __init__.py
   wizard
   __init__.py
```

example_module/`__init__.py`

```
from . import models
from . import wizard
```

example_module/models/`__init__.py`

```
from . import example_file_1.py
from . import example_file_2.py
from . import connectors
```

example_module/models/connectors/`__init__.py`

```
from . import Constants
from . import example_connector_1.py
from . import example_connector_2.py
```

I would like to use the contents of Constants.py inside example_connector_1.py and example_connector_2.py.

Current situation (`example_module/models/connectors/example_connector_1.py`):

```
import Constants
print(Constans.EXAMPLE_API_KEY)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Constants'`

File Constans.py contains only constant variables (API keys and tokens).
If possible I would really like to avoid adding anything to `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
from . import Constans
```

If you are Using Pycharm it helps you with autofill so It will be easy to see the scope.